# Return an object with out keyword from Dictionary Lookup

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, static, return

Here is my code:

```
namespace BingAdsDataImporter
{
    class DeveloperDetails
    {

        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string DeveloperToken { get; set; }

    }

    static class CollInit
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, DeveloperDetails> details = new Dictionary<string, DeveloperDetails>()
        {
            { "Clientnamehere", new DeveloperDetails {ClientId="xxx", DeveloperToken="xxxx"} }
        };

        public static DeveloperDetails GetValue(string key)
        {
            if ( details.TryGetValue(key, out DeveloperDetails) ) // fails here Error   1   'BingAdsDataImporter.DeveloperDetails' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
            {
                return dd;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Where this is failing is on  the static method GetValue(string key).
I want to return either a DeveloperDetails object or perhaps create another method for the token and change this method name to return the key. I cannot return the object with the out keyword (though I don't know why) and I cannot figure out how to return a specific value from that object, which is preferred. Any help is appreciated.

**Fixed here are my new methods**

```
    public static DeveloperDetails GetObjectDetails(string key)
    {
        DeveloperDetails dd = null;
        if ( details.TryGetValue(key, out dd) )
        {
            return dd;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
    public static string GetClientId(string key)
    {
        DeveloperDetails dd = null;
        if (details.TryGetValue(key, out dd))
        {
            return dd.ClientId;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
    public static string GetDeveloperToken(string key)
    {
        DeveloperDetails dd = null;
        if (details.TryGetValue(key, out dd))
        {
            return dd.DeveloperToken;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: "out DeveloperDetails" is invalid.  You need to give it an object to output to.

DeveloperDetails dd = null;
if( details.TryGetValue...)

The above should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StriplingWarrior's answer is the one you're looking for.

However, if you wanted to return only one value from developerDetails:

```
public static string GetValue(string key)
{
    DeveloperDetails dd;
    if ( details.TryGetValue(key, out dd) )
    {
        return dd.ClientID;  //or dd.DeveloperToken
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `out` keyword requires a variable to put the value into:

```
    public static DeveloperDetails GetValue(string key)
    {
        DeveloperDetails dd;
        if ( details.TryGetValue(key, out dd) )
        {
            return dd;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Since the `out` parameter will be left `null` if the value is not in the dictionary, this can further be simplified as:

```
    public static DeveloperDetails GetValue(string key)
    {
        DeveloperDetails dd;
        details.TryGetValue(key, out dd);
        return dd;
    }
```

Or (in a shameless plug for a framework I've written), you can use an extension from the [`CallMeMaybe`](https://bitbucket.org/j2jensen/callmemaybe) library:

```
    public static DeveloperDetails GetValue(string key)
    {
        return details.GetMaybe(key).Else(() => null);
    }
```

If you're going to use this last approach, you may consider eliminating the `GetValue` method entirely, and have the calling code leverage the `Maybe<>` type. For example:

```
string clientId = details.GetValue(key).ClientId; // could throw null reference
```

... becomes

```
Maybe<string> clientId = details.GetMaybe(key).Select(d => d.ClientId);
```

Comment: I am interested in seeing that library you have written :D I have learned that the 'out' keyword requires a variable declaration above it, which is strange to me, but whatever.

Comment: I'm up voting just because you have a library called `CallMeMaybe`.  Do you also have `ThisIsCrazy` and `HeresMyNumber` libraries? ;)

Comment: @RadleyAnaya: I added a link. It basically helps you avoid null references by putting a compile-time construct around the idea of things that might not be there.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thanks for the link. I have a question, why do you use Bitbucket over GitHub? I am curious because I just learned that Bitbucket is a thing. (im a noob)

Comment: @RadleyAnaya: Bitbucket allows you to create private repositories for free, so I use it more often for stuff that I don't want everyone to be able to see. Also, at the time I created that library, I was more used to working with Mercurial than Git, and Github doesn't support Mercurial repos.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Upvoted because I need a way to create FREE PRIVATE REPOS. That is very helpful information to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public static DeveloperDetails GetValue(string key)
    {
        DeveloperDetails dd = null;
        if ( details.TryGetValue(key, out dd) )
        {
            return dd;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

The DeveloperDetails you are giving is the return type definition. Out however needs to be passed a variable name.